# Project specific Nuget.config with .net core/code

Tags: nuget, .net-core, nuget-package-restore

Normally, we get our Nuget.config from `users\[loggedinuser\AppData\Roaming\Nuget` but we have a case where a specific project where we need a use a different project specific config file.  Where do I place the config file in this case?

I am using .net core SDK 1.0.4 and .net code.

The build script does this:

```
cd src\SFMC.Adapter.Service
dotnet restore
dotnet build
```

Can I pass an argument into `dotnet restore` to indicate the location of the config?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming your project structure looks like:

```
Project/
└── src
    ├── SFMC.Adapter.Client
    ├── SFMC.Adapter.Service
    │   ├── Program.cs
    │   └── Project.csproj
    └── SFMC.Adapter.Service.Test
```

You can add a Nuget file anywhere within the project tree. Where you place it will affect which projects see it by default. `dotnet restore` will search for all `Nuget.config` files up the directory tree to add any sources it finds.

If you place it next to `Service.cs`, it will only be picked up by `SFMC.Adapter.Service`. If you place it under `src` it will be picked up and used by `SFMC.Adapter.Service`, `SFMC.Adapater.Service.Test` and `SFMC.Adapter.Client`.

See [NuGet configuration docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior#how-settings-are-applied) for more details.

Comment: minor input: NuGet will pick it up only for the file you run the restore on, so a project reference from test-> service shouldn't pick up the config located in the service project if you restore from within the test project.

Comment: But the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior#config-file-locations-and-uses say: _In a solution folder, settings apply to all projects in subfolders. Note that if a config file is placed in a project folder, it has no effect on that project._

Answer (score 11):

I know it is a rather old post, but I was struggling with it as well and had a hard time finding the correct documentation. I eventually found that you can execute the command below to add a new nuget config to the location where you are.
`dotnet new nugetconfig`

This will use the dotnet cli to use the nugetconfig template (that appeared to be installed by default) to generate a correct file

Comment: Confirmed that this is the best answer, Thanks , you saved my day.

Answer (score 6):

From the [Nuget docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior#config-file-locations-and-uses):

> Project-specific `NuGet.Config` files located in any folder from the solution folder up to the drive root. These allow control over settings as they apply to a project or a group of projects.

So you can put a Nuget config file alongside the project file to give that project a specific configuration.